# JQuery Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

What's wrong with this:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>    #CAR_NO>option[value=486]

The main idea is that I have a dropdown and I have search that filters this dropdown and when I click an item after search this item should be selected but I keep getting this error for this case even though the code works well in other pages and forms

*EDIT* (code from the comments)

> HTML code:

```
<select name="car_no" id="CAR_NO" class="search">
<option value="0" > --------- </option>
<?php 
foreach($vars['CARSLIST'] as $row) { 
?>
<option value="<?=$row['CAR_NO']?>"><?=$row['CAR_NO']?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

> jQuery code:

```
var result = $("#"+OptionId+">option:contains("+$("#keyword").val()+")");    
for(i=0;i<result.length;i++){
FinalResult +=\'<div title="" style="cursor:pointer;" id="\'+result[i].value+\'">\'+result[i].text+\'</div>\'} 
$("#result").html(FinalResult);
```

Comment: Showing us a little more code would be useful. Just an error message is not much for us to go on

Comment: you need to show your code, otherwise we can't help you!

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: this is the html code
            <select name="car_no" id="CAR_NO" class="search">
             <option value="0" > --------- </option>
             <?php foreach($vars['CARSLIST'] as $row) { ?>
              <option value="<?=$row['CAR_NO']?>"><?=$row['CAR_NO']?></option>
             <? }?>
            </select>

jquery code

var result = $("#"+OptionId+">option:contains("+$("#keyword").val()+")");
     for(i=0;i<result.length;i++){FinalResult +=\'<div title="" style="cursor:pointer;" id="\'+result[i].value+\'">\'+result[i].text+\'</div>\'}
     $("#result").html(FinalResult);